# Not able to retrieve hasGroups or groups claims in the Access Token, using the ADAL sample application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I created a 
1. temporary tenant in portal.azure.com
2. Created temporary users and groups in the tenant (The source of these users is AAD)
2. Register an application to the tenant and the application manifest is as follow.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpCr0.png)

When used a sample application and login using authorization_code workflow , still not able to see the hasGroups or group claims as part of my access_token

Can anyone help regarding this.

Comment: Have you looked at the id token?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you. 
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I am using this [code sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/) to test the group claims. I can get the groups from the access token successfully.

[image]

Here are the main steps.

1.new application registration.

2.set the value of "groupMembershipClaims" to "SecurityGroup"

3.configure permissions for your application. To that extent, in the Settings menu, choose the 'Required permissions' section and then, click on Add, then Select an API, and type Microsoft Graph in the textbox. Then, click on Select Permissions and select Directory.Read.All. Do remember to click grant permission button at last.
[image]

4.configure the sample to use your Azure AD tenant.
[image]